# Initialize a Class variable with date function?

Tags: php

I am trying to do this:

```
class A {
 public $var1 = date('U');
}
```

But, obviously, above is failing due to Syntax Error.

Can someone let me know of an alternate way of doing this.

I have around 100s of such dateTime variable and hence, using a constructor is not really what can be beneficial, however, I am still waiting for anyway possible to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it `static` if you truly want it to be a class variable:

```
class A {
   public static $var1 = date('U');
}
```

Or, if you want it to be an instance variable:

```
class A {
   public $var1;
   function __construct() {
      $this->var1 = date('U');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Jacob's answer is not entirely correct.

Put simply, you **cannot** make function calls from within a class and outside of a function.

This

```
class A {
   public static $var1 = date('c');
}
```

Will not work as you are still making a call to `date()`

But if you must, then

```
class A {
   public static $var1;
        public function __construct()
    {
        static::$var1 = date("c");
    }
}
```

Use `self` or `static` to instantiate your variable within the class constructor. Both do [different things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718808/php-can-static-replace-self).