# How to get static data member from php object instance?

Tags: php, oop, static

Hi does someone know how can I access public static data member of a PHP class from instance of that class?

Comment: well are you facing any error doing like this `$object->$data_member` ?

Comment: Em... `self::$variable`?

Comment: static access is done on the class, not on an instance of a class, otherwise its not static access its plain public access. Example of  Static access: NameOfClass::StaticVariable

Comment: or AbstractClassName::$variable if not in the class.

Comment: or static::$variable if you are in a derived class

Comment: How is it difficult to tell what is being asked? Obviously it's a case of using polymorphism where one doesn't know the class of the object, only that it inherits one common ancestor. So you need to somehow access static fields and functions through the instance variable of unknown class and not a class name.

Answer (score 3):

E.g. via

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function bar() {
        echo '-> '. self::$data . ' <-';
    }

    public static $data = 'FooData';
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar();
```

see also: http://php.net/language.oop5.late-static-bindings

Comment: [`$foo::$data` will also work](http://3v4l.org/ehiME) for PHP >= 5.3.0

Comment: Yes. The question is open for interpretation; i chose the one where the member had to be accessed from "within" the instance ;-)

Comment: It's better to use `static` keyword over `self` in case of [inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718808/php-can-static-replace-self)

Comment: FDL , that depends on what you're trying to achieve. But yes, that's why I linked to the late static binding man page.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that - you still had my upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about PHP but you cannot access static members of class from it's instance. static members are one per type not one per instance.

Comment: Static member is one per type, but you can access to it from instance.

Comment: I don't know about php. But in OOP the convention is that static members can only be access by the call to type. You don't have access to any static field from the concrete instance of the class.

Comment: @Dima, then how do you use static fields and functions with objects of unknown class with the common ancestor? Is this a bad practice?