# Php class and static properties inside constructor

Tags: php, class, properties, constructor, static

Is it possible to change the default value of a static class property inside the constructor in php?

```
class Test { 
  public static $property = 'default';

  public function __construct() {
    self::$property = 'new value';
  }       
}
```

The code above doesn't do that.
Thanks in advance!

**EDITS**

I know I can change the value outside the class

```
Test::$property = 'new value';
echo Test::$property;
```

I was wondering if I could do it inside class constructor.

Comment: `$a = new Test(); echo Test::$property;` print `new value`

Comment: Your test code should work, perhaps you should post you *real* code

Comment: instead of using `self::$property` you might consider using `static::$property` which allows for more dynamic usage: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718808/php-can-static-replace-self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PHP 5.3, you can use the late static binding.

Replace "self" by "static" in your code :

```
class Test { 
  public static $property = 'default';

  public function __construct() {
    static::$property = 'new value';
  }       
}
```

It will works ;)

Comment: Yes it works when the class is initialized first, but not accessing it directly with just Test::$property that's what constructor is for $test = new Test(); Test::$property then it works perfectly :)

Comment: I didn't know that you would like to do this ! So, you must write a getter for this property.

Comment: Replacing "self" with "static" should not be necessary. The sample code should work as described. However noting the difference between "self" and "static" is important.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a double point:

```
self::$property = 'new value';
```

Comment: That was just a typing mistake here

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
class Test { 
  public static $property = 'default';
  public function __construct() {
     echo self::$property = 'new value'; // for EXample echo val of property
  }       
}
//When create a new object of class it shows / Assigns value of static property

$test = new Test();
echo Test::$property;
```