# retrieve information from a mysql from database using PHP OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am very confused about this problem I am having.  I am trying to get information from my database, but it only partly works.  I have a function named authenticate in my user.php file in a class of User that extends DatabaseObject.

```
class User extends DatabaseObject{

protected static $table_name = "sellatext_users";  
public $id;  
public $email;
public $password;
public $fname;
public $lname;

public static function authenticate($email="", $password="") {
   global $database;
   $email = $database->escape_value($email);
   $password = $database->escape_value($password);

   $sql  = "SELECT * FROM ".static::$table_name;
   $sql .= " WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
   $sql .= "AND password = '{$password}' ";
   $sql .= "LIMIT 1";

   $result_array = static::find_by_sql($sql);
   var_dump($result_array);
   die;
   return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
}
```

This works fine, and if I var_dump($result_array) I get

```
array(1) { 
       [0]=> object(User)#5 (5) 
               { 
                 ["id"]=> string(1) "3" 
                 ["email"]=> string(18) "email_address" 
                 ["password"]=> string(8) "XXXXXXXX" 
                 ["fname"]=> NULL 
                 ["lname"]=> NULL 
               }
         }
```

Email_address and password are omitted for security, but I can't figure out why I am getting NULL for both the fname and the lname.  There is information in there in the table (it is my name) since I can access the table through Navicat.  Both fields are varchar fields.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?
Thank you.

Comment: Using `gloabl` in a class method is very poor coding, it totally destroys the encapsulation of the class. As you have extended that DatabaseObject class, can you not use `$this->database->....`

Comment: my DatabaseObject extends a class called Database in a different file, if not using global ( the tutorial I learned from showed it that way) how am I supposed to get the database info?

Comment: If each class `extends` the previous one then using `$this->a_property` will look at the current object for $a_property and if not found will look up the extended class hierarchy for the property until it finds it. It does not matter if the classes are defined in different physical files, as long as each new class extends i.e. subclasses, the previous one. If your tutorial suggested using `global` in a class structure then find a better tutorial.

Comment: so instead of global $database I should be using $database = $this->database;?

Comment: No, remove the global line. Then where ever you have used `$database` replace it with `$this->database->xxx` so for this line `$database->escape_value($email);` change it to  `$this->database->escape_value($email);`

Comment: Made the changes and got this error:PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /includes/user.php on line 16, which is the $this->database->escape_value($email);  I will keep adjusting my code to correct the error, but I am still trying to resolve the fact that it is returning null for my fname and lname fields.

Comment: To be sure of my ground I would have to see how all the classes are actually defined. So best ignore this for now.

Comment: Are you sure you dont have 2 rows where email and password match your criteria but one that has nothing in the fname and lname columns?

Comment: There is only one record in that table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I set up a repo on git here: https://github.com/jimdimag/sellatext.git so you can see the whole thing and possibly help me out.  Thanks for all your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM ".static::$table_name;
```

To

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM ".self::$table_name;
```

Also,

```
$result_array = static::find_by_sql($sql);
```

to

```
$result_array = self::find_by_sql($sql);
```

You need to use word [self](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) instead of `static`

Comment: Static works as I am getting results from the query, so why so I need to change them from static to self?  Will that get me the last fields that I am missing?

Comment: @Jim Read this, this will clear up stuff about self and static. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718808/php-can-static-replace-self

Comment: I made the changes and I am still getting NULL for the fname and lname, so I don't think that makes a difference